# How to explain the result of using tostring() on an object

Tags: javascript, tostring

According to MDN ,

> By default, the toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object . If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString() returns " [object type] ", where type is the object type.

My first question is that what does object type means? Does it mean Array, Function, Object, Date? I had searched object type in google but I can't find a comprehensive explaination.
Consider the following example

```
const toString = Object.prototype.toString; toString.call(new Date);
toString; toString.call(new Date);    // [object Date]
toString.call(new String);  // [object String]
toString.call(Math);        // [object Math]
```

I don’t understand why toString.call(new String) returns [object String]
From the MDN, it should return [object type] where the type should be object in this case
because console.log (new String) print out {" "} which is an object. [object String] also seems contradictory as String is not a type of Object, String is Primitive

Comment: isn't toString used to convert a number into a string? 3.toString(); // returns "3"

Answer (score 0):

> String is not a type of Object, String is Primitive

In a sense, everything in JavaScript is an `object`.  Even primitives like `String`, because [except for `null` and `undefined`, all primitive values have `object` equivalents that wrap around the primitive values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

> "I don’t understand why toString.call(new String) returns [object
>   String] From the MDN, it should return [object type] where the type
>   should be object in this case because console.log (new String) print
>   out {" "} which is an object. [object String] also seems contradictory
>   as String is not a type of Object, String is Primitive"

You seem to be reading it wrong.

This is a *String* **literal** `""` whereas this `new String` is a *String* **object** .
However both (literals and objects) will read from their corresponding Object constructors so result will be generic, that is [object String] for both kinds of instances :: be it `""` or `new String`.

I think you got mixed with the terminology in use; which is: a bit redundant. JavaScript has 7 ***types*** of which some are *objects* (notice the use of lower case in the name ) one of them is the object Object**. That is an *object* of the **type** Object.

Anyway, you can have a *primitive\literal* as well as an *object* of the corresponding *type*, but they are not the same! The behavior of a Number `5` *literal* in comparison to a Number *object* `new Number(5)`, is very different.

Answer (score 0):

One might consult [*"8.6.2 Object Internal Properties and Methods"*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) as of ECMAScript 5 for a deep-dive into this matter.

But for a more comprehensive reading I do recommend Axel Rauschmayer's article [*"Improving the JavaScript typeof operator"*](https://2ality.com/2011/11/improving-typeof.html), especially section *2.1 Getting the type name: the [[Class]] property*

---

Anyhow ... from the first source the following paragraph is the most important one ...

> The value of the [[Class]] internal property is defined by this specification for every kind of built-in object. The value of the [[Class]] internal property of a host object may be any String value except one of **"Arguments"**, **"Array"**, **"Boolean"**, **"Date"**, **"Error"**, **"Function"**, **"JSON"**, **"Math"**, **"Number"**, **"Object"**, **"RegExp"**, and **"String"**. The value of a [[Class]] internal property is used internally to distinguish different kinds of objects. Note that this specification does not provide any means for a program to access that value except through **Object.prototype.toString** [(see 15.2.4.2)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2).

... and the last reference then does state ...

> **15.2.4.2 Object.prototype.toString()**
>
> When the **toString** method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the **this** value is **undefined**, return **"[object Undefined]"**.
> 2. If the **this** value is **null**, return **"[object Null]"**.
> 3. Let *O* be the result of calling [ToObject](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9) passing the **this** value as the argument.
> 4. Let *class* be the value of the [[Class]] internal property of *O*.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings **"[object "**, *class*, and **"]"**.

... now, taking all of the above into account, if one does provide `new String`, which is an object type and not a primitive value, via `call` as context to the `toString` method of `Object.prototype`, one does retrieve `String` as the [[Class]] internal property.

But, and ***@GirkovArpa*** already was pointing to it, if one does run the same procedure with a string value, this primitive, for the time being processed, will be raised to / wrapped into a related object type (Step 3 ... [ToObject](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9)), here `String`, which again corresponds with the [[Class]] internal property.

Thus, ***`'[object String]'`*** will be the return value for both last mentioned cases ...

```js
function exposeInternalClassSignature(type) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(type);
}

console.log(
  '"internal class signature for" ...',
  '"foo"',
  ' ... ',
  `"${ exposeInternalClassSignature('foo') }"`
);

console.log(
  '"internal class signature for" ...',
  (new String('bar')),
  ' ... ',
  `"${ exposeInternalClassSignature(new String('bar')) }"`
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```